# How long does Wubi take to download and/or save place?

Tags: 11.04, installation, wubi, downloads

I'm downloading Wubi now and it's been downloading the ISO torrent for maybe 2hrs-ish. Is there anyway to check how far along it is?

Also, is there a way to save my place or if I cancel this or my computer dies, will it lose the place?

If I DO lose my place. Can I download a ISO myself and place it somewhere that Wubi will grab from so it just installs it, not downloads the ISO? (this way I can watch the % too)

Im at a conference and my internet is fluctuating between 3-7MBs...if that helps

Comment: if WUBI fails to download the torrent , or the iso file if you choose so, youwill have to start all over again as it is a temporary file, it is saved in a tmp folder but i don't remember where.

Answer (score 2):

Wubi, just as any other download will only download as fast as your internet connection allows.

Answer (score 2):

I used to download the ISO (via torrent, http), mount it using [ImageDisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk), and then run Wubi from the mounted disk.